# How to describe return value of Class?

Tags: typescript, class, factory, typescript2.0

I need to explicitly describe the return type of function in typescript. It so happens that the return value will always be a class. Unfortunately, the following doesn't work:

```
interface IFoo {
    bar()
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    public bar() {}
}

function func(): IFoo {
    return Foo
}
```

> Property 'bar' is missing in type 'typeof Foo' but required in type
> 'IFoo'.ts(2741)

Moreover, this also generates an error:

```
function func(): Foo {
    return Foo
}
```

> Property 'bar' is missing in type 'typeof Foo' but required in type
> 'Foo'.ts(2741)

Is it possible to give the function some meaningful description of return value?

Comment: Can you give an example of how the `func()` function should be called/how its return value would be used?

Comment: You should look at what your code does in [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyRyARnFABQCU+AvvvggDZwDOryWOwAtgA5MIPCOA4ZseQsT4BXEk2AJS5annr18MGSARhgmEMi07qALjRdJxZFAhgZUQ1zpA)

Comment: 1. Define what `IFoo.bar()` returns. 2. Update `Foo.bar()` to return the same thing. 3. Change `func()` to `return new Foo();`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an instance of the class `Foo`, which implements `IFoo`. When you simply `return Foo`, you're returning the definition of the class, not an instance of the class.

```
interface IFoo {
    bar()
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    public bar() {}
}

function func(): IFoo {
    return new Foo()
}
```